# Flux - Isn't it a bad practice to include the dispatcher instance everywhere?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flux

*Note: My question is about the way of including/passing the dispatcher **instance** around, not about how the pattern is useful.*

I am studying the [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) Architecture and I cannot get my head around the concept of the dispatcher (instance) potentially being included everywhere...

What if I want to trigger an Action from my Model Layer? It feels weird to me to include an **instance** of an object in my Model files... I feel like this is missing some injection pattern...

I have the impression that the exact PHP equivalent is something (that feels) horrible similar to:

```
<?php
$dispatcher = require '../dispatcher_instance.php';

class MyModel {
    ...
    public function someMethod() {
        ...
        $dispatcher->...


    }
}
```

I think my question is not exactly only related to the Flux Architecture but more to the NodeJS "way of doing things"/practices in general.

Comment: The singleton dispatcher is because you want one place where all the events in your application flow (be it API requests/responses or user interaction). It's more-or-less a form of [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).

Comment: "It feels weird to me to include an instance of an object in my Model files" --- it feels indeed, since your models should not care about it. Models' purpose is to hold the data.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR:

- No, it is not bad practice to pass around the instance of the dispatcher in your stores
- All data stores should have a reference to the dispatcher
- The invoking/consuming code (in React, this is usually the view) should only have references to the action-creators, not the dispatcher

Your code doesn't quite align with React because you are creating a public mutable function on your data store.

The **ONLY** way to communicate with a store in Flux is via [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) which always flows through the dispatcher.

For example:

```
var Dispatcher = require('MyAppDispatcher');
var ExampleActions = require('ExampleActions');

var _data = 10;
var ExampleStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

  getData() { 
    return _data;
  },

  emitChange() {
    this.emit('change');
  },

  dispatcherKey: Dispatcher.register(payload => {
    var {action} = payload;
    switch (action.type) {
      case ACTIONS.ADD_1: 
        _data += 1;
        ExampleStore.emitChange();
        ExampleActions.doThatOtherThing();
        break;
    }
  })

});

module.exports = ExampleStore;
```

By closing over `_data` instead of having a `data` property directly on the store, you can enforce the message passing rule. It's a private member.

Also important to note, although you can call Dispatcher.emit() directly, it's not a good idea.

There are two main reasons to go through the action-creators:

1. *Consistency* - This is how your views and other consuming code interacts with the stores
2. *Easier Refactoring* - If you ever remove the `ADD_1` action from your app, this code will throw an exception rather than silently failing by sending a message that doesn't match any of the switch statements in any of the stores

### Main Advantages to this Approach

- Loose coupling - Adding and removing features is a breeze. Stores can respond to any event in the system with by adding one line of code.
- Less complexity - One way data flow makes wrapping head around data flow a lot easier. Less interdependencies.
- Easier debugging - You can debug every change in your system with a few lines of code.

debugging example:

```
var MyAppDispatcher = require('MyAppDispatcher');
MyAppDispatcher.register(payload => {
  console.debug(payload);
});
```

Comment: Hi Duncan, thx for thorough answer. I agree with you that it is not a bad practice to pass the dispatcher to the Stores which are singletons as well anyway (instances, not class definition). My concern is more about the pure Model layer, for example when your Stores consume/use a specific Model, instanciate it, etc.. And this model needs to use the dispatcher for the reasons you've highlighted in your answer. Then I **think** I would have to inject the dispatcher in the Model constructor. Thx.